# Data Structure(AP_IntX) in Ardupilot

Tags: c++, data-structures

Recently i've been reading the source code of Ardupilot

[ardupilot github](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot)

There are some data structures looks like AP_Int8 but i cannot find the definition of them. This is a code snippet in parameters.h

```
AP_Int8 takeoff_flap_percent;  
AP_Int8 inverted_flight_ch;             // 0=disabled, 1-8 is channel for inverted flight trigger
AP_Int8 stick_mixing;
```

However it does not looks like the simple Integer because in the source code I find that this AP_Intx has some methods in it, so it looks like a class

```
//Parameters.h
AP_Int16 format_version;

//Plane.h
// Global parameters are all contained within the 'g' and 'g2' classes.
Parameters g;
ParametersG2 g2;

//Parameters.cpp
// save the current format version
g.format_version.set_and_save(Parameters::k_format_version);
```

So the format_version has a method called set_and_save( ). I believe that AP_Int8 or AP_Int16 are some kind of structured classes but I really cannot find their definitions. I want to know all the methods in this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of macros in `AP_Param/AP_Param.h` that define `AP_...` types, including `AP_Int8`.
See [here](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/blob/ec0b073fbca34b3c8b70908eb2fcd46888365f6f/libraries/AP_Param/AP_Param.h#L787).